# Adjusting a reproduced table

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I am trying to reproduce the following table in latex:[image]

For this, I am using the following code:

```
      \documentclass[12pt,oneside, brazil]{article}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage{textcase}

      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
      \usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=purple]{hyperref}
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{
        a4paper,
        left=30mm,
        top=30mm,
        right=20mm,
        bottom=20mm
      }
      \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
      \usepackage{makecell}
      \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
      \usepackage{float}
      \begin{document}

      \begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{0.99999\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}             & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{PRODUCERS AS CONSUMER}                                           & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{FINAL DEMAND}                                           \\ \cline{3-14} 
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}                              & Agric. & Mining & Const. & Manuf. & Trade & Transp. & Services & Outher & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{Personal\\ Consumption\\ Expenditures}} & \makecell{Gross Private\\ Domestic\\ Investiment} &\makecell{ Govt.\\ Purchases of\\ Goods $\&$ \\Services} & \makecell{Net Exports \\of Goods $\&$\\ Services}\\ \hline
        \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{PRODUCERS}} & Agriculture          &     \cellcolor{gray!25}        &         \cellcolor{gray!25}   & \cellcolor{gray!25}           & \cellcolor{gray!25}           &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          & \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}       &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Mining            &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &     \cellcolor{gray!25}       &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &     \cellcolor{gray!25}        &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &     \cellcolor{gray!25}    &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Construction            &     \cellcolor{gray!25}         &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}     &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}     &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &     \cellcolor{gray!25}    &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Manufacturing             &       \cellcolor{gray!25}       &    \cellcolor{gray!25}        &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &    \cellcolor{gray!25}        &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &    \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}   &      \cellcolor{gray!25}   &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Trade              &       \cellcolor{gray!25}       &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}     &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &   \cellcolor{gray!25}      &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Transportation            &     \cellcolor{gray!25}         &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}     &     \cellcolor{gray!25}      &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          &    \cellcolor{gray!25}       & \cellcolor{gray!25}        &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Services              &    \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &     \cellcolor{gray!25}       &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &         \cellcolor{gray!25}    &      \cellcolor{gray!25}     &       \cellcolor{gray!25}  &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \cline{2-14} 
        & Outher Industry               &        \cellcolor{gray!25}      &   \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &    \cellcolor{gray!25}         &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &      \cellcolor{gray!25}   &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \hline
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{VALUE ADDED}}}           & Employees              & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Employee compensation}                                             & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{GROSS DOMESTIC PRODUCT}}                  \\ \cline{2-10}
        & \makecell{Business\\ Owners and\\ Capital }& \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Profit-type income and capital consuption allowances}             & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                        \\ \cline{2-10}
        & Government            & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Indirect business taxes}                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
           \end{document}
```

[image]

But the end result is not getting any closer. For example, the font has become very small, I was unable to adjust the cell size when I rotate a word, for example, the word VALUE ADDED was not inside the cell and the gray cells do not have the outline, as shown in the figure.

Could anyone help me? Please

Comment: The font size is so small because of the resizebox command.

Comment: I don't think you can fit this table onto a portrait page while keeping a readable font size. You could either split this table into multiple subtables or rotate it t a landscape orientation.

Comment: What will the actual contents of the gray cells look like? Probably you can save some more space there.

Comment: @VictorHugo you have a side heading of Producers and then Value Added under that-- why not put the Final Demand subtable between  Producers and Value Added--that way more space available

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion using a table on a landscape page, `\footnotesize` and a smaller `\tabcolsep` to make sure the table fits into the page, `cellspace` for a bit more space between text and horizontal lines and `hhline` for horizontal lines in the gray colored area:

(In the following screenshot some lines seem to be missing. This is due to the pdf viewer. Compile the code and zoom in further to see all lines.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, brazil]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcase}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=30mm,
  top=30mm,
  right=20mm,
  bottom=20mm
}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand{\mycline}{\hhline{|~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|}}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=purple]{hyperref}
      \begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

      \begin{table}[H]
      \footnotesize
      \centering
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{14}{Sl|}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|Sl|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}             & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{PRODUCERS AS CONSUMER}                                           & \multicolumn{4}{Sc|}{FINAL DEMAND}                                           \\ \cline{3-14} 
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}                              & Agric. & Mining & Const. & Manuf. & Trade & Transp. & Services & Outher & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{Personal\\ Consumption\\ Expenditures}} & \makecell{Gross Private\\ Domestic\\ Investiment} &\makecell{ Govt.\\ Purchases of\\ Goods $\&$ \\Services} & \makecell{Net Exports \\of Goods $\&$\\ Services}\\ \hline
 \multirow{13}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{PRODUCERS}}        & Agriculture          &     \cellcolor{gray!25}        &         \cellcolor{gray!25}   & \cellcolor{gray!25}           & \cellcolor{gray!25}           &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          & \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}       &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline
        & Mining            &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &     \cellcolor{gray!25}       &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &     \cellcolor{gray!25}        &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &     \cellcolor{gray!25}    &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline  
        & Construction            &     \cellcolor{gray!25}         &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}     &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}     &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &     \cellcolor{gray!25}    &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline 
        & Manufacturing             &       \cellcolor{gray!25}       &    \cellcolor{gray!25}        &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &    \cellcolor{gray!25}        &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &    \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}   &      \cellcolor{gray!25}   &                                                  &              &      &     \\  \mycline
        & Trade              &       \cellcolor{gray!25}       &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}     &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &   \cellcolor{gray!25}      &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline 
        & Transportation            &     \cellcolor{gray!25}         &      \cellcolor{gray!25}      &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &       \cellcolor{gray!25}     &     \cellcolor{gray!25}      &   \cellcolor{gray!25}          &    \cellcolor{gray!25}       & \cellcolor{gray!25}        &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline
        & Services              &    \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &  \cellcolor{gray!25}          &     \cellcolor{gray!25}       &  \cellcolor{gray!25}         &         \cellcolor{gray!25}    &      \cellcolor{gray!25}     &       \cellcolor{gray!25}  &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \mycline 
        & Outher Industry               &        \cellcolor{gray!25}      &   \cellcolor{gray!25}         &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &        \cellcolor{gray!25}    &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &    \cellcolor{gray!25}         &   \cellcolor{gray!25}        &      \cellcolor{gray!25}   &                                                  &              &      &     \\ \hline
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{VALUE ADDED}}}           & Employees              & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Employee compensation}                                             & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{GROSS DOMESTIC PRODUCT}}                  \\ \cline{2-10}
        & \makecell[l]{Business\\ Owners and\\ Capital }& \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Profit-type income and capital consuption allowances}             & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                        \\ \cline{2-10}
        & Government            & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Indirect business taxes}                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
           \end{document}
```